# Mini Table of Content \minitoc drove itself crazy (i was on board) ... how to fix?

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

I am using minitoc.

In the main file,

```
\usepackage[english,tight]{minitoc} 

... 

...


\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\frontmatter 
...
...
\input(myChapter_one)
```

And at each chapter (separate file)

```
\chapter{Chapter name}

\minitoc


...

...
```

It was working fine until today. Now, what I can see, for example in chapter 5, minitoc is not synchronized, it says chapter 4 like, 4.1.2 .. ..4.2....

AND,

There is no minitoc on chapter One!  [`\minitoc` command is still on the chapter one too!]

Can you please give me some clues?

Comment: I'd start by deleting the `\jobname.mtc*` files, re-compile twice, and see if anything changes. If that doesn't work, make a copy of your document, and start stripping it down until you have a MWE. If you can't debug the MWE, post it as part of your question so that folks have something to work with :)

Comment: Before you do my first suggestion- make sure that you have either `\tableofcontents` or `\faketableofcontents` in your pre-amble

Comment: +1 for *"`\minitoc` drove itself crazy (i was on board)"*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the important thing missing from your document is either `\tableofcontents` or `\faketableofcontents`.

Without one of these, the `minitoc` package will not update the `\jobname.mtc*` files appropriately. From your description, it sounds like the `minitoc` package is working from 'old' `\jobname.mtc*` because you are seeing chapter 4's `minitoc` in chapter 5.

Here is MWE

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\begin{document}

\dominitoc
\faketableofcontents    % need either this line 
%\tableofcontents       % or this one for minitoc to work

\include{chapter1}

\end{document}
```

If this doesn't help, please post more details in your question.